# Pandas dataframe type datetime64[ns] is not working in Hive/Athena

Tags: python, pandas, hive, amazon-athena, fastparquet

I am working on a python application which just converts csv file to hive/athena compatible parquet format and I am using fastparquet and pandas libraries to perform this. There are timestamp values in csv file like `2018-12-21 23:45:00` which needs to be written as `timestamp` type in parquet file . Below is my code that am running ,

```
columnNames = ["contentid","processed_time","access_time"]

dtypes = {'contentid': 'str'}

dateCols = ['access_time', 'processed_time']

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=keyname)

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"', names = columnNames, error_bad_lines=False, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=dateCols)

s3filesys = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

myopen = s3filesys.open

write('outfile.snappy.parquet', df, compression='SNAPPY', open_with=myopen,file_scheme='hive',partition_on=PARTITION_KEYS)
```

the code ran successfully , below is the dataframe created by pandas

```
contentid                 object
processed_time            datetime64[ns]
access_time               datetime64[ns]
```

And finally , when i queried the parquet file in Hive and athena , the timestamp value is `+50942-11-30 14:00:00.000` instead of `2018-12-21 23:45:00`

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Try converting the columns to data time format while inserting in hive

    pd.to_datetime(df['access_time', 'processed_time'], unit='ms', errors='coerce')

Comment: tried that as well. but still it is the same

Comment: Don't parse columns while creating DF, instead convert to datetime object as datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-12-21 23:45:00','%y-%m-%d %H:%m') and apply to date columns of df.

Comment: You might need to use a function from here https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html depending on the format generated by your python script if it is not directly supported by Athena/Hive.Use "parquet-tools cat" to check the data and schema for schema.Post the timestamp format here if you are not able to find correct function for conversion.

Comment: Did any of these answers help, I'm running into the exact same issue?

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old but it is still relevant.

As mentioned before Athena only supports int96 as timestamps.
Using fastparquet it is possible to generate a parquet file with the correct format for Athena. The important part is the times='int96' as this tells fastparquet to convert pandas datetime to int96 timestamp.

```python
from fastparquet import write
import pandas as pd

def write_parquet():
  df = pd.read_csv('some.csv')
  write('/tmp/outfile.parquet', df, compression='GZIP', times='int96')
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
dataframe.to_parquet(file_path, compression=None, engine='pyarrow', allow_truncated_timestamps=True, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by this way.

tranforms the df series with [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method

next with a [.dt accesor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) pick the date part of the datetime64[ns]

Example:

```
df.field = pd.to_datetime(df.field)
df.field = df.field.dt.date
```

After that, athena will recognize the data

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Athena, it only seems to support int96 and when you create a timestamp in pandas it is an int64

my dataframe column that contains a string date is "sdate"  I first convert to timestamp

```py
# add a new column w/ timestamp
df["ndate"] = pandas.to_datetime["sdate"]
# convert the timestamp to microseconds
df["ndate"] = pandas.to_datetime(["ndate"], unit='us')

# Then I convert my dataframe to pyarrow
table = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)

# After that when writing to parquet add the coerce_timestamps and 
# use_deprecated_int96_timstamps. (Also writing to S3 directly)
OUTBUCKET="my_s3_bucket"

pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset(table, root_path='s3://{0}/logs'.format(OUTBUCKET), partition_cols=['date'], filesystem=s3, coerce_timestamps='us', use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem for multiple times.
My error code is I set the index to datetime format by:

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index), inplace=True)
```

When I then read the parquet file by fastparquet it may notice me that

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 219968-03-28 05:07:11
```

However, it can be easily solved by using `pd.read_parquet(path_file)` rather than `fastparquet.ParquetFile(path_file).to_pandas()`

PLEASE USE `pd.read_parquet(path_file)` TO FIX THIS PROBLEM

That's my solution and it works well, hope it may help you then you don't need to worry about how to write parquet in which way.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem, after a lot of research, it is solved now.

when you do

```
write('outfile.snappy.parquet', df, compression='SNAPPY', open_with=myopen,file_scheme='hive',partition_on=PARTITION_KEYS)
```

it uses fastparquet behind the scene, which uses a different encoding for DateTime
than what Athena is compatible with.

the solution is: uninstall fastparquet and install pyarrow

- pip uninstall fastparquet
- pip install pyarrow

run your code again. It should work this time. :)