# Azure Synapse Serverless -- Unexpected end of stream loading parquet in Azure Synapse Serverless pool

Tags: t-sql, parquet, azure-synapse

Trying to load the following parquet file, results in an `Unexpected end of stream` error. Perhaps the parquet file is corrupted?

### intended query

```sql
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK N'/path/to/my.parquet',
        DATA_SOURCE='my_blob_datasource',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
) as somehow_necessary_alias
```

### error statement

```
Statement ID: {1F956C7F-FA37-4D34-AC0D-D4BDF8336160}
Query hash: 0x729ED47717032037
Distributed request ID: {5815A501-2179-4968-BE71-3B7AACFE717C}.
Total size of data scanned is 27 megabytes,
total size of data moved is 290 megabytes,
total size of data written is 0 megabytes.

Msg 15813, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Error handling external file: 
'Unexpected end of stream'. File/External table name:
https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/path/to/my.parquet
```

Comment: Could you attach the file as well?

Comment: @maya-msft no file, but I've at least provided an explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we found out the answer, but I couldn't make a reproducible example that I could share, but I'll give as much explanation as I can. The parquet file was created by `pandas.to_parquet()` using the `pyarrow` engine. There's currently an arrow bug where an as-of-yet un-diagnosed pandas index quick translates to an extra column being added at the end named `"__index_level_0__"`. I imagine this is what was surfacing the `Unexpected end of stream` error.

This issue was first flagged as a [`pandas` issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34790), but then moved to an [Arrow Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-9136) which has a reproducible example.

However, our scenario was different in that we weren't using `pandas.to_parquet()`'s `partition_cols` param, so something else kooky was going on. Fortunately, the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#handling-indexes) touch on this by suggesting the following:

> the code below creates a parquet file with three columns if you use
> `pyarrow` for serialization: a, b, and `__index_level_0__`. If you’re
> using `fastparquet`, the index may or may not be written to the file.
>
> `python df.to_parquet("test.parquet", engine="pyarrow")`
>
> This unexpected extra column causes some databases like Amazon
> Redshift to reject the file, because that column doesn’t exist in the
> target table.
>
> If you want to omit a `dataframe`’s indexes when writing, pass
> `index=False` to `to_parquet()`

p.s. if you're using `pandas` to create parquet files for upload into Synapse, be sure to pass `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True` to `to_parquet()` so Synapse will properly parse your datetime columns. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919763/pandas-dataframe-type-datetime64ns-is-not-working-in-hive-athena) for related info

Answer (score 1):

I repro’d the scenario and was able to run the query successfully in the Azure Synapse Serverless SQL pool.

[image]

**Note**: Make sure you have the access to the file and ensure you are using UTF-8 database collation.

You can go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-parquet-files#read-parquet-file) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the version of `parquet.net` I was using incorrectly wrote `Int16` data (see issue here: https://github.com/aloneguid/parquet-dotnet/issues/16). I changed the property to just be an `Int32` and the error went away.